# Set time restrictions for certain websites even on admin

Tags: parental-controls

Is there a way to set time restrictions per day on certain websites like YouTube on my own admin account?  (preferably free)

I tried the application [SelfControl](https://selfcontrolapp.com/) , but there aren't many options, and I have to set it every time I want to block websites.

If nothing, what other tips are there to limit myself from distracting websites?

Comment: Did you try [WasteNoTime](http://www.bumblebeesystems.com/wastenotime/) already?

Comment: No, thanks, I haven't heard of that one. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit YouTube or other time-consuming sites with your web browser you can install either WasteNoTime ([Safari](http://www.bumblebeesystems.com/wastenotime/download/WasteNoTime-current.safariextz) or [Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wastenotime/enebomhlllfaccbelnjhfgblnalofhch)) or LeechBlock ([FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/)). WasteNoTime is/was inspired by LeechBlock.

The extension (I only tested it in Chrome) is adequately adjustable by using blacklists and whitelists.

By adding *chrome://extensions* to the block list you can even hinder yourself disabling or uninstalling the extension.

These extensions are not infallible though: you can still just remove it using the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Freedom](https://freedom.to) service. It has nice free features as well as extended paid ones.